# yet another @font-face-not-working-on-IE issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, internet-explorer-8, font-face, font-awesome

First off I would like to mention that I probably read 50 other topics on this problem but nothing I tried works for me.

I am using [font-awesome-rails gem](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) to integrate FontAwesome with my rails 3.1 app.

In Development, icons are loading fine in all 3 major browsers (FF, Chrome and IE7,8).

In Production (Heroku), icons are only loading in FF and Chrome. I get square boxes in IE7 & 8.

I can't really say if this is a browser issue because it works on my local machine, but also can't really say it is a deployment issue because it works in other browsers.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

Below is the CSS generated by asset pipeline. Notice how .woff and .tff files have digest hash appended to them, but that is not the case for .eot & .svg files. This could explain why fonts are not loaded on IE in production.

Is there anything I can do to fix this or is this something that the gem owner should fix?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("eot"), 
         url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont-2b313d88274b814fa936513279e62429.woff") format("woff"), 
         url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont-db4d858c72934d23138b334666f3787f.ttf") format("truetype"), 
         url("/assets/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome") format("svg");
}
```

Comment: in prod, when viewing from your machine, it's not ok? im sure you tried, but did you clear your cache?

Comment: Yes, i tried clearing my cache but no luck. does not work in prod, only in dev.

Answer (score 0):

I added an additional style as such

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.eot', font);
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Rails correctly applies digest hash to this asset and IE picks it up.